# VBA No resultset from stored procedure that backups database

Tags: sql-server, vba

I need to execute a stored procedure that make some changes to a specific database and back it up at the same time. For some reason, when the backup code is active, in VBA's recordset I don't get any row but the backup is effectively created.

The recordset comes closed and Err.Description is "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed." If I comment the backup code in the stored procedure, the recordset comes opened I get the 1 row with the results.

In the vb code I am calling the stored procedure with adAsyncExecute and waiting using the following code:

Any Idea why the recordset comes closed and does not return 1 row when executing successfully the sp?

**Edit:**
If I execute the sp in SSMS with exec, it works and I can see the row with the values.
[image]

**12.01.2015**

- I found exactly the same issue for another user but no solution
  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7e05bc02-4681-4d08-9c21-b90d5730c7e6/receiving-recordsetresultset-from-sql-server?forum=sqlexpress
- I tried to execute the sp  in synchronous mode and I face the same issue
- It is not a timeout problem. Currently command's timeout is 180 seconds  and the sp takes around 40 seconds to finish.

**VB code:**

```
             sDB = "master"
             TrustedConnection = True
             ReDim arrPara(1, 2)
             arrPara(0, 1) = sStandardDatabaseSTR: arrPara(1, 1) = "@DATABASE"
             arrPara(0, 2) = 1: arrPara(1, 2) = "@STEP"
             Set rs = ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR("dbo.Frozen_Generation", adCmdStoredProc, arrPara, , True)
             Do While rs.ActiveCommand.State = adStateExecuting 'or 4
                'sleep 1000
                DoEvents
             Loop
             rs.MoveFirst <-- Here I got the closed recordset when using the backup block
```

**ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR code:**

```
Function ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR(ByVal sSQL As String, CommandType As CommandTypeEnum, Optional arrParameter As Variant, Optional iQueryTimeout As Variant, Optional async As Boolean = False) As ADODB.Recordset
   On Error GoTo errHandler
   LogToFile currentModule, "ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR", "exec " & sSQL & " " & SerializeArray(arrParameter)
   Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
   Dim para As ADODB.Parameter
   Dim blFound As Boolean
   Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, iType As Variant

Start:
    cmd.ActiveConnection = DBconnSTR

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 180

    If Not IsMissing(iQueryTimeout) Then
      cmd.CommandTimeout = iQueryTimeout
    End If

    If blDebugSTR Then Debug.Print sSQL

    If CommandType = 4 Then
        If Not IsMissing(arrParameter) Then
            blFound = False
            For i = 0 To cmd.Parameters.Count - 1
                If cmd.Parameters(i).Name <> "@RETURN_VALUE" Then
                    For j = 0 To UBound(arrParameter, 2)
                        If cmd.Parameters(i).Name = arrParameter(1, j) Then
                            cmd.Parameters(i) = IIf(arrParameter(0, j) = "", Null, arrParameter(0, j))

                            #If DEBUG_MODUS = 1 Then
                              Debug.Print cmd.Parameters(i).Name & " - " & cmd.Parameters(i).value
                           #End If
                            blFound = True
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

            Next
            If cmd.Parameters.Count = 0 And UBound(arrParameter, 2) >= 0 Then
                For i = 0 To UBound(arrParameter, 2)
                    If Not IsNumeric(arrParameter(0, i)) Then
                     'adVarBinary
                        If TypeName(arrParameter(0, i)) = "Byte()" Then
                           iType = adLongVarBinary
                        Else
                           iType = adVarChar
                        End If
                    Else
                        iType = adInteger
                    End If

                    Set para = cmd.CreateParameter(arrParameter(1, i), iType, adParamInput, 250)
                    cmd.Parameters.Append para
                    cmd.Parameters(arrParameter(1, i)) = arrParameter(0, i)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If InStr(1, sSQL, "?", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrParameter, 2)
            cmd.Parameters(i) = arrParameter(0, i)
        Next
    End If


    Set ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR = New ADODB.Recordset
    If (async) Then
        ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adAsyncExecute
    Else
        ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    End If

exit_me:
   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Function

errHandler:
   LogToFile currentModule, "ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR", Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description
   Debug.Print Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description
   If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
      Set m_ADO_STR = Nothing
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
      Resume Start
   End If
   If Err.Number = 3709 Then Resume Start
   If Err.Number = -2147217911 Then
      'No Rights to Execute
      MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR of Modul mdlDatabase"
   End If
   If Err.Number = -2147217871 Then
      MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ADO_OpenParameterQuerySTR of Modul mdlDatabase"
   End If


   Resume exit_me
   Resume

End Function
```

**SP code:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Frozen_Generation]
(
    @DATABASE as varchar(100),
    @STEP as int
)
AS
--general
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @now DateTime

DECLARE @resStep1_1 int
DECLARE @resStep1_2 int
DECLARE @resStep1_1_ERR varchar(200)
DECLARE @resStep1_2_ERR varchar(200)

--backup
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(90);
DECLARE @db_name VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @now = GETDATE()

    if (@STEP=1) begin

        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@SettingsValueBIT int, @SettingsName varchar(100), @UpdatedOn smalldatetime';
        SET @SQLQuery = 
        N'use ' + @DATABASE + ';
        UPDATE dbo.A_ConfigSettings set SettingsValueBIT=@SettingsValueBIT, UpdatedOn=@UpdatedOn  where SettingsName=@SettingsName'
        EXECUTE @resStep1_1 = sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @ParmDefinition, @SettingsValueBIT=0, @SettingsName='APP_Status',@UpdatedOn=@now;


        -- Make backup (If I comment this block, I got 1 row in the recordset)
        BEGIN TRY
            SET @fileName = 'E:\backups\'; -- change to the relevant path 
            SET @db_name = 'frozenwizard';     -- change to the relevant database name 
            SET @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),112);
            SET @fileName = @fileName + @db_name + '_' + RTRIM(@fileDate) + '.bak';
            SET @SQLQuery = N'BACKUP DATABASE '+@DATABASE+' TO DISK = ''' + @fileName + ''''
            EXECUTE @resStep1_2 = sp_executesql @SQLQuery
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT @resStep1_2=ERROR_NUMBER(), @resStep1_2_ERR=ERROR_MESSAGE();
        END CATCH

        SELECT
         @resStep1_1 as resStep1_1, coalesce(@resStep1_1_ERR,'') as resStep1_1_ERR
         @resStep1_2 as resStep1_2, coalesce(@resStep1_2_ERR,'') as resStep1_2_ERR

    end

END
```

Comment: How do you call this SP?

Comment: Can you post all the output when executing the procedure in SSMS? This is just a suggestion, but try calling rs.NextRecordset after the call returns. Perhaps the rows you're looking for is not the first resultset.

Comment: @Spock Thanks for the suggestion but the stored procedure only returns 1 resultset. Anyway I tried rs.NextRecordset but no luck.